# Creating a WordPress Page in my plugin to Export MySQL data as CSV

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, csv, download

I am looking to create a page in my wordpress plugin in which Export MySQL data from table  as CSV and download it on click.I have following code

```
<?php
function fz_csv_export() {
$date = new DateTime();
$ts = $date->format( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' );
$result = array();
$result[] = array(
"first_name" => "Faison", "last_name" => "Zutavern",
"product_viewed" => "Sunglasses", "time_viewed" => $ts
);
$result[] = array(
"first_name" => "Faison", "last_name" => "Zutavern",
"product_viewed" => "Razor", "time_viewed" => $ts
);
$filename = "report-$ts.csv";
header( 'Content-Type: text/csv' );
header( 'Content-Disposition: attachment;filename='.$filename);
$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
$hrow = $result[0];
fputcsv($fp, array_keys($hrow));
foreach ($result as $data) {
fputcsv($fp, $data);
}
fclose($fp);
}
// Execute the function
fz_csv_export();
?>
```

but it prints the data rather than download csv.Any help is appreciate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the PHP documentation stated at: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

> Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is
>   sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP.
>   It is a very common error to read code with include, or require,
>   functions, or another file access function, and have spaces or empty
>   lines that are output before header() is called. The same problem
>   exists when using a single PHP/HTML file.

Just pass your headers at the beginning of the script, this will ensure that the headers are passed properly and the file can be downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Use This at place of csv file generating code

`$filename = "report-$ts.csv";`

```
    header( 'Content-Description: File Transfer' );
    header( 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $filename );
    header( 'Content-Type: text/csv; charset=' . get_option( 'blog_charset' ), true );

    $fields="id".","."Name"."\n";
```

Fetch content from foreach loop

`foreach
       {
       $data .= $id.",".$name."\n";
       }`

```
   echo $fields.$data;
   exit;
```